# Compute time constant of discrete exponential decay pulses

Tags: filters, discrete-signals

I want to retrieve (within a FPGA) the time constant $\tau$ of incoming pulses of the form $$x[n]=Ae^{-n/\tau}u[n]+C$$
In addition to the offset, inputs are subject to noise.

To measure the integral of the pulses, I used a trapezoidal filter (2 successive differentiator+accumulator) whose properties allow for DC offset removal and noise attenuation. Starting from that, I was wondering if there is were a smart way to compute an approximation of the time constant.

A few articles mention Fourier Transform or Corrected Successive Integration technics but I could not find any free material.

Any tip to put me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: so by using your DC offset removal filter, does that mean that $C$ is zero?

Comment: The filter is just to measure the integral of the pulse, and one of its property is to remove the offset

Comment: my question remains.

Comment: and may i suggest modifying your equation to be completely discrete-time?  like this: $$x[n]=Ae^{-n/\tau}u[n]+C$$  and use small-case $x[\cdot]$ for functions of time and leave the capital $X[\cdot]$ for frequency domain.

Comment: I edited the formula. Yes the filter removes the offset, so C does not matter and can be considered zero.

Comment: so do you know how to do Least Squares fit?  if no, i will spell it out in an answer, but that will have to be later.

Comment: I must say that I don't know much about it. Thank you for your help

Comment: looks like Dawg pointed you to another answer.  i am still *"on the road"*.  see if that other answer helps, but if you want one that takes many more than 4 samples and computes $\tau$ using a least-square fit, then you might need something else.  but Dawg's answer is a good one, i think.

Comment: I am really interested in knowing how your approach differs from Dawg's one

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I would too.  The only approach I can think of that uses a least squares method would be a gradient descent of ($\tau,A,C$).  If you can assume $C$ is zero, then you can kick it to a log scale and do a linear regression fit (also least squares, but in the log domain).  My approach is a calculation formula for the decay, then a standard linear algebra approach to a best fit for the other two parameters.  The OP only asked for the decay rate.  The referenced answer is not needed for that, it is for finding $A$ and $C$.

Comment: Pulses have an offset so I cannot assume $C=0$. I do not need to know C. A is unknown, but I calculate it by applying a coefficient (which is a parameter) to the output of my trapezoidal filter. This coefficient is function of a theorical $\tau$ as shown in my [previous post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53192/recursive-filter-gain/53193#53193) as an example, and I did the same methodology for the trapezoidal filter. The decay depends on the electronics upfront and my only way to get a precise coefficient is to get a precise decay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take four sample values.

$$ y_1 = x[p] $$
$$ y_2 = x[q] $$
$$ y_3 = x[p+d] $$
$$ y_4 = x[q+d] $$

Subtract the third from the first.  Notice that the $C$s cancel out.

$$ y_1 - y_3 = x[p] - x[p+d] = Ae^{-p/\tau}-Ae^{-(p+d)/\tau} =  Ae^{-p/\tau} \left( 1 - e^{-d/\tau} \right) $$

Similarly, subtract the fourth from the second.

$$ y_2 - y_4 = Ae^{-q/\tau} \left( 1 - e^{-d/\tau} \right) $$

Take the quotient of these two differences.  Notice that the $A$s cancel out.

$$ \frac{y_1 - y_3}{y_2 - y_4} = e^{(q-p)/\tau} $$

Take the log of each side.

$$ \ln \left( \frac{y_1 - y_3}{y_2 - y_4} \right) = \frac{q-p}{\tau} $$

Solve for $\tau$.

$$ \tau = \frac{q-p}{ \ln \left( \frac{y_1 - y_3}{y_2 - y_4} \right) } $$

I did this more thoroughly in another [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/least-squares-fitting-to-inverse-exponential-function), but this should give you start.  You want the differences to be large compared to the noise level, meaning d should be large.  $(q-p)$ being larger will help too.  I am guessing that four evenly spaced samples are as good as anything.  Something to investigate.

If noise is a problem you can spread the calculation across more points.  You can either do an average of neighbor points for each $y$ value as long as you use the same weighting or employ more points directly in the quotient as in my referenced answer.

The other answer will also show you how to find the best fit values of $A$ and $C$.

---

Using more points to mitigate noise.

Here is a way you can fully utilize all your samples to reduce the effects of noise I believe as much as possible.

Select the number of samples ($N$) to be a multiple of four.  Partition the samples into four quarters.  Then set the $y$ values to be the sum of the samples of the corresponding quarters.  You don't need to take an average (an extra division) because that washes out in the taking of the quotient.

$$ q-p = N/4 $$

In addition to taking one measure of the entire curve, you might want to try a sliding window taking many smaller measures.  The values you get should be fairly constant.  If not, your assumption of exponential decay may not be correct.

---

Sample Python code:

```
import numpy as np

#================================================
def main():

#---- Set Parameters

        A   = 1.234
        C   = 5.678
        tau = 24.08016032

        N = 100

#---- Construct the pulse

        x = np.zeros( N )

        for n in range( N ):
            x[n] = A * np.exp( -n / tau ) + C

        print x

#---- [Add noise here]

#---- Example Using a Single Point

        p = 10
        q = 20
        d = 20

        y1 = x[p]
        y2 = x[q]
        y3 = x[p+d]
        y4 = x[q+d]

        S = ( y1 - y3 ) / ( y2 - y4 )

        #++[Check S here]

        tau_calc1 = ( q - p ) / np.log( S )

        print tau_calc1

#---- Example by Quarters

        y1 = np.sum( x[p:p+10] )
        y2 = np.sum( x[q:q+10] )
        y3 = np.sum( x[p+d:p+d+10] )
        y4 = np.sum( x[q+d:q+d+10] )

        S = ( y1 - y3 ) / ( y2 - y4 )

        #++[Check S here]

        tau_calc2 = ( q - p ) / np.log( S )

        print tau_calc2

#================================================
main()
```

Comment: Thank you Dawg. Your answer and the reference post are a lot to digest for me, but I think that get the point. I am going to test the second part and take the measure with all the samples. The noise is a real problem, especially for small pulses. I will provide the results on real pulses as soon as I get back to my laptop

Comment: @Dams0622,You're welcome.  You will get better results at the steeper part of your curves.  This is because the differences you will be taking will be larger compared to your noise level.  When the curve gets close to flat the difference gets close to zero and value becomes almost all noise, a very poor SNR.  The nice thing about this solution is that it is fairly efficient.  It would be nice to see some results.

Comment: @Dams0622, I have added some sample code to show that the formulas work in the noiseless case.  As you can see, the calculations are pretty straightforward.  You may get a better read by finding the best fit $A$ and $C$ then casting away the outliers and recalculating.

Comment: I reproduced your script in Excel (my only tool available at the moment) and it is working really well. I will be able to produce results with real pulses in a few days