# Does it make sense to express a given FT from 0 to 1 as a convolution?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, convolution

I'm learning about Fourier transform, and was asked whether the following FT can be expressed as a convolution: $$X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N=1} x[n]e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$$

There are two things I don't understand:

1. Why would anyone want to express the FT itself as a convolution? from what I understand, FT is *used* to express convolution, as stated by the Convolution Theorem.
2. Assuming it does make sense to express an FT as a convolution, how can we do that with the above FT?

Comment: Are you sure that it says $N=1$ on top of the sum, instead of $N-1$, i.e., a general formula for a length $N$ DFT?

Comment: I'm sure as I can be

Comment: Also the term 'FT' is used for the continuous case, DFT for the discrete.  CTFT if FT is too bland or ambiguous, depends on context.

Comment: It can be seen like this, a weighted sum of Roots of Unity:

$$ X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]\left( e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}k} \right)^n  = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]R_k^n  $$

and it can be seen as a dot product:

$$ X[k] = (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],...,x[N-1]) \cdot ( 1, e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}}, e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}2},  ... e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}(N-1)} ) $$

but in either case the summation does go up to $N-1$ so you can never be too sure.

Comment: You should probably read this too.  Maybe that is where the '1' comes from. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69430/amplitude-after-fourier-transform/69432#69432

Answer (score 1):

As for the *why*, it's always good to come up with alternatives, even if one doesn't immediately see their benefit. In this case it's about efficiency, especially if the FFT length is a prime. The resulting algorithm can also be used to solve the more general problem of computing (samples of) the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform on circles or spirals in the complex plane. You can also zoom into a certain frequency region without the need to compute the DFT over the whole range.

The resulting algorithm is called [Bluestein's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform#Bluestein%27s_algorithm) or [Chirp Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform). The basic trick to represent the DFT (or $\mathcal{Z}$-transform) by a convolution is to write

$$nk=\frac{n^2+k^2-(n-k)^2}{2}\tag{1}$$

and use this expression in the original formula. This results in the representation of the original DFT sum by $(i)$ a multiplication of the original sequence with a chirp sequence, $(ii)$ a convolution, and $(iii)$ another multiplication with a chirp sequence. The details are explained in the link cited above.